# borderlayout is not loading full on the screen

Tags: google-maps, zk, zul

I'm new in ZK and I'm trying to load map but it is not loading full because of vflex = "min".
I'm able to see half screen but not seeing any scroll. I have tried to set vflex = "full", "1" and "max" but still borderlayout is not loading in full. Below is the code of zul file:

```
<vlayout>
                                        <div/>
                                        <borderlayout vflex="min">
                                            <west>
                                                <vlayout>
                                                    <vlayout/>
                                                    <groupbox width="280px">
                                                        <listbox height="240px"/>
                                                        <hlayout>
                                                            <button/>
                                                            <button/>
                                                        </hlayout>
                                                    </groupbox>
                                                </vlayout>
                                            </west>
                                            <center>
                                                <vlayout>
                                                    <hlayout spacing="2em">
                                                        <vlayout>
                                                            <label/>
                                                            <slider/>
                                                        </vlayout>
                                                        <vlayout>
                                                            <label/>
                                                            <checkbox/>
                                                        </vlayout>
                                                        <vlayout hflex="1">
                                                            <label/>
                                                            <slider hflex="1"/>
                                                        </vlayout>
                                                    </hlayout>
                                                    <hlayout>
                                                        <vlayout>
                                                            <label/>
                                                            <doublebox/>
                                                        </vlayout>
                                                        <vlayout>
                                                            <label>
                                                            <doublebox/>
                                                        </vlayout>
                                                        <vlayout>
                                                            <label>
                                                            <textbox/>
                                                        </vlayout>
                                                        <vlayout>
                                                            <label/>
                                                        </vlayout>
                                                    </hlayout>
                                                    <hlayout hflex="1">
                                                        <div hflex="1" >                                    
                                                            <div>
                                                                <script/>
                                                                <gmaps height="800px"/>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </hlayout>
                                                </vlayout>
                                            </center>
                                        </borderlayout>
                                    </vlayout>
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates the issue so that the community could help you better. I tried this code in the ZK sandbox and it doesn't seem to work. Please provide a working one.

Answer (score 0):

I put your zul on https://zkfiddle.org/sample/3ght56j/1-borderlayout-is-not-loading-full-on-the-screen

It looks like:
[image]

Is this what you expected? Could you decribe more clear about " not loading full "? or post a screenshot?